# How to flatten an image using OpenCV correctly for image processing and then convert it to Mat again?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, mat, flatten

I have an image, read using "cv::imread". I have to flatten it so that I could use CUDA & GPU for my image processing algorithms acceleration.

My problem: When I read my image, I can show it correctly using imshow, however when I flatten it and convert it to a Mat object to be used with imshow, only part of my image is displayed. The size of the output image is also wrong, meaning that some data is really lost. What's the problem with my for loop?

```
// The problematic part of my code
// The Camera Man gray test image
const char* img_gray_name = "../../Test_Images/cameraman.tiff";
const char* img_blur_name = "../cameraman-blur.tiff";
const char* image_general_name = "cameraman_blur";
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(img_gray_name);
unsigned long int img_gray_size = img.rows * img.cols * sizeof(uchar);

uchar *h_img_in;// input image, converted to a flat array to be 
                    // processed by GPU
h_img_in = (uchar *)malloc(img_gray_size);

//*************** The bug should be here! ***************//
for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j) {
        h_img_in[i*img.cols+j] = img.at<uchar>(i, j);
    }
}

Mat img_test;
img_test = Mat(cv::Size(img.cols, img.rows), CV_8U, h_img_in);
imwrite(img_blur_name, img_test);
// create image window named "camera man"
cv::namedWindow(image_general_name);
// show the image on window
cv::imshow(image_general_name, img_test);
```

*P.S.: I also tested with a new 2D array instead of 1D h_img_in, result is the same; This means that something goes wrong with my usage of "img.at(i, j)".*

Comment: First of all, since the second parameter to `imread` is not provided, it defaults to `IMREAD_COLOR`, so `img` actually has 3 channels, not 1 as you seem to assume. | Second, if the `Mat` is continuous (which output of `imread` generally will be), it already holds the data in a "flat array", so all you really need is to call `img.ptr()`.

Comment: Dear @DanMašek thanks for your prompt response. I changed my imread to IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and my problem resolved. Thanks a lot.